# scrollPositionRestoration 'enabled' breaks anchor navigation in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I have html that comes from cms, in this html there is anchor navigation (FAQ page). When I have `scrollPositionRestoration` enabled on `RouterModule`, I need to click twice on anchor to navigate to proper id. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some other solution, because I'd really like to have `scrollPositionRestoration` enabled. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with custom implementation, as described in [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration).
Mine looks like this:

```
if (event instanceof Scroll) {
    if (event.position && !event.anchor) {
        this._viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(event.position);
    }

    if (event.anchor) {
        this._viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(event.anchor);
    }

    if (!event.position && !event.anchor) {
        this._viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    }
 }
```